“email: Unable to save user:” Craft Solo & Commerce 5: Guest Checkout fails
I am running Commerce 5 on a Craft Solo edition but am struggling with guest checkouts. Error Message: email: Unable to save user:. Nothing more. Logs aren’t helpful as well.
Commerce seems eager to create a new user when updating the address on the cart which it can’t since there is one one user allowed. There is no guest checkout setting anywhere to m knowledge so it has to be done in the templates.
What are the special requirements for guest checkouts on Craft Solo? How do I suppress the need to associate a guest with a user?

I imagine a 'Guest' in this context is simply an un-priveleged, un-authenticated user, against which the order is stored. Not sure how else Craft would be able to create an order, if not against a user?
